# How to properly install FLTK with/in Cygwin?

Tags: netbeans, makefile, cygwin, mingw, fltk

I have tried continuously to install fltk into cygwin with no luck. I have been successful to install it to msys but i cant use msys in netbeans and i personally prefer cygwin.

-->After i have extracted the FLTK 1.3.2 tar file

-->I ran this in cygwin in the fltk directory (c:/fltk/)

`sh configure --prefix=/usr/local/fltk --enable-localjpeg --enable-localzlib --enable-localpng`

--> When i run `make` after the previous input, I get this:

`Archiving ../lib/libfltk_jpeg.a...
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, /cygdrive/c/MinGW/bin/ar cr ../lib/libfltk_jpeg.a jaricom.o jcapimin.o jcapistd.o jcarith.o jccoefct.o jccolor.o jcdctmgr.o jchuff.o jcinit.o jcmainct.o jcmarker.o jcmaster.o jcomapi.o jcparam.o jcprepct.o jcsample.o jctrans.o jdapimin.o jdapistd.o jdarith.o jdatadst.o jdatasrc.o jdcoefct.o jdcolor.o jddctmgr.o jdhuff.o jdinput.o jdmainct.o jdmarker.o jdmaster.o jdmerge.o jdpostct.o jdsample.o jdtrans.o jerror.o jfdctflt.o jfdctfst.o jfdctint.o jidctflt.o jidctfst.o jidctint.o jmemmgr.o jmemnobs.o jquant1.o jquant2.o jutils.o, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make[1]: *** [../lib/libfltk_jpeg.a] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 1`

Comment: i think it may be because my cygwin is 64 bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cygwin already has FLTK. Use the Cygwin installer, find the package, and install it.